# Kindless ancestor query for different entity kinds in golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/queries#kindless_ancestor_queries), it should be possible to retrieve an ancestor and all of its descendants, regardless of their kind.

In my implementation, I have a different kind of ancestor and descendant. The following codes however always returns the error "invalid entity type":

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("").Ancestor(tomKey)
t := q.Run(ctx)
for {
    var x interface{}
    _, err := t.Next(&x)
    if err == datastore.Done {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "Error fetching entity: %v", err)
        break
    }
}
```

It seems that the call to t.Next(&x) expects a specific type instead of an empty interface. Would somebody please help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the documentation is wrong, but you can use `datastore.PropertyList` to fetch arbitrary value. like this:

```
    var v datastore.PropertyList
    key, err := iter.Next(&v)
    ...

    props, err := v.Save()
    ...
```

See [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#PropertyList) for more information.

Comment: Works properly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @fsapei Good luck! accepting this answer is welcome :)